# valarray in-place operation gives different result as a temporary assignment

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, in-place, valarray

the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<valarray>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int init[] = {1, 1};

  // Example 1
  valarray<int> a(init, 2);
  // In-place assignment
  a[slice(0, 2, 1)] = a[slice(0, 2, 1)] + valarray<int>(a[slice(0, 2, 1)]) * a[0];

  for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++ k) {
    cout << a[k] << ' ';  // Outputs 2 3
  }
  cout << endl;

  // Example 2
  valarray<int> b(init, 2);
  // Temporary assignment
  valarray<int> r = b[slice(0, 2, 1)] + valarray<int>(b[slice(0, 2, 1)]) * b[0];
  b[slice(0, 2, 1)] = r;

  for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++ k) {
    cout << b[k] << ' '; // Outputs 2 2
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
2 3
2 2
```

The correct answer is `2 2` (`<1 1> + <1 1> * 1 = <2 2>`. Why is the inline version outputting something different?

In case it matters, I'm compiling this way:

```
g++ myprogram.cpp -o myprogram
```

And the output of `g++ -v` is:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)
```

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `a[slice(0, 2, 1)]` has type `slice_array<T>`, and there is no overload of `operator+` taking an `slice_array<T>` object or reference as parameter.

Note the possible working overload `operator+(const valarray<T>&, const valarray<T>&)` is a function template, though `slice_array<T>` can be implicitly converted to `valarray<T>`, the template argument `T` cannot be deduced from the `slice_array<T>` argument.

So strictly speaking, your code will cause a compile error. In fact, [Clang does](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NehzuNKaJhPbTX8M).

---

Second, you should know there are some optimization techniques for operations of `valarray`. One well-konwn technique is [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates), which causes your unexpected results. To see how it works, let's consider a simpler example that reproduces this problem:

```
valarray<int> a{1, 1};
a = a + a[0];
// now a is {2, 3} while {2, 2} is expected
```

The key idea of expression templates is to postpone the evaluation of expression until its value is really needed, such that extra temporary is avoided.

In the example above, an optimizer may choose to optimize the result of `a + a[0]` to be a proxy object instead of a `valarray<int>` temporary. The proxy object just stores the **action** (not the result value) of "adding `a[0]` to `a`".

When the proxy object is then assigned to `a`, actual evaluation occurs. From the stored action, the optimizer will choose to assign `a[i] + a[0]` to `a[i]` for each `i`. Now different evaluation orders in this assignment will result in different results. For example, if the compiler assigns `a[0] + a[0]` to `a[0]`, and then assigns `a[1] + a[0]` (here `a[0]` is changed to 2) to `a[1]`, the unexpected result `{2, 3}` is produced.

The standard allows such proxy object to exist, but it seems not clearly to specify how the proxy object should work. I personally think this is a compiler bug, because simply evaluating `a[0]` and storing its value before assignment will solve this problem with little performance loss.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a missing template overload with the older compiler. [Template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator%3D)

`valarray<T>& operator=( valarray<T>&& other ) noexcept;`

exists in VS2017 and in [gcc-7.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/libstdc++/api/a01723_source.html) but absent in [older](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/valarray-source.html) versions. The expression on the right seems to be evaluated and assigned every iteration. The simplest example demonstrating this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

int main() 
{

    std::valarray<int> a{2, 4, 8};
    a = a + a[0];

    for (auto n : a) 
        std::cout << n << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The [correct](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e564f9923a035ac7) output is:

```
4 6 10
```

However older compilers [produce](https://ideone.com/96OqyN)

```
4 8 12
```

Solution would be to use updated compiler or [force copy](https://ideone.com/5zG56r)

```
a = std::valarray<int>(a + a[0]);
```

Hope this helps